# How to go back in different folder by using base_url?

Tags: php

I have a ROOT, which has path of my project. Now, I am inside subfolder, and assets is outside of the subfolder. so how to get outside by using ROOT.
// output of ROOT is  G:\xampp\htdocs\admin_main\ 
MY current folder is G:\xampp\htdocs\admin_main\dashboard\agent\manage.php 
In manage.php I have multiple image tags and my images are in assets, which is in admin_main folder.
I can go easily by using like this 
But, my task is to do that by using ROOT.

Comment: The ideal solution is highly dependend on your setup and code. It doesn't make much sense as posted. Why don't you just use `ROOT . "/assets/filename.img"`?

Comment: I tried, but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parent directory with `../`

Since you made an edit to your post, this should work:

```
$path = "../../assets/"
```

but since I guess you're using this inside HTML only, you can do:

```
<img src="/assets/img1.jpg" />
```

Comment: What do you want to do anyway? Is the manage.php accessable and which path is shown in address bar?